# What does a type name in parentheses before a variable mean?

Tags: objective-c, casting

I am having a bit of trouble understanding this piece of code. It is from a book I am reading but I feel like the guy is just telling me to type stuff without explaining it in much depth.

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender; //set slidervar as active slider
    int progressAsInt = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
    NSString newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",progressAsInt];
    sliderLabel.text = newText;
    [newText release];
}
```

the issue is with the first line

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender; //set slidervar as active slider
```

I do not understand what typecasting is, which is what the guy says in the book. "avoids needing to typecast sender everytime we use it"

I also do not understand what/why the second line has `int` in brackets. I am used to having code like

```
int progressAsInt = 56
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typecasting is a method of telling the compiler that something is a different type than it is. It is involved in both parts of your question. You cast something by placing the new type in parentheses before the item you are casting.

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
```

When the method is declared, `sender` has a type of `id`. Since you know it is supposed to be a slider, you cast it to `UISlider *` and store it in a variable with that type so that the compiler doesn't give you warnings when you try to use slider specific properties.

```
int progressAsInt = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
```

Here, `slider.value` is a floating point number. Since you want to store it in an integer type, you need to cast it. When a float is cast to an int, it is automatically rounded toward zero. The code wanted it rounded to the nearest integer, so it added 0.5 before casting.

Comment: how come when you cast sender it has a * but when you cast the slider value it only has int in brackets?

Comment: The `*` means that it is a pointer. It is used for all objective-c objects, because they are all pointers to the object data. However, `id` is defined as a pointer already, so it does not get one. When you use `int`, you say that the variable directly holds the number, and you don't want a pointer to the number.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you don't understand C. Objective-C is a thin layer over C that adds classes and messaging. Check a good C book, such as one from ["The Definitive C Book Guide and List"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Without obtaining a reference to the object that is typed as `UISlider *`, you would be unable to use the property syntax without, at each instance, casting the `sender` reference to the desired type, for example, `((UISlider *)sender).value`. Even if you weren't using property dot notation, a cast would also be necessary to get the compiler to treat `[slider value]` as returning anything other than an `id`.

The book as is just being silly, though. There's no requirement that the argument to an action method be typed as `id`. When you know that the sender is always going to be of a certain type – as in this case, where the code assumes that `sender` is always going to be a kind of `UISlider` – you can just use that type in the method declaration:

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    /* code */
}
```

This better documents the programmer's intent – documentation that Interface Builder picks up on – as well as completely eliminating the need to do any casting within the method.

In general, if you need to typecast, there's a good chance you're doing something wrong.

As another example, let's look at this line:

```
int progressAsInt = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
```

Here, the explicit `int` typecast is unnecessary. Because the assignment is to an `int` lvalue, the floating point value that results from the addition would necessarily be coerced to an `int` as part of the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the computer (compiler, actually, but we can pretend for simplicity's sake) only knows what kind of thing you are referring to because of its "type". The type could be an `int, or`UISlider *`, or any number of other things. It is a classification for a variable.

At the top, you can see that `sender` is of type `id`, which means the computer has no idea what kind of object it is.

When this method is called, you receive an object which is called `sender`. But even though you know that sender is a `UISlider*`, you can't call UISlider methods on it, because the *computer* doesn't know that.

When you say `UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;`, you are saying "Hey computer, I'm telling you that sender is a `UISlider *`, and I'm going to refer to it as `slider` from now on. That is what typecasting is.

The same goes for `int progressAsInt = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);`

`(slider.value + 0.5f)` is actually a `float`, which is alike a number with decimals. You can't just assign a float to a variable meant for `int`s, so instead you say "Please turn this  float into an int for me", by putting the `(int)` in front.

Comment: Actually, you *can* just assign a float to a variable meant for `int`s. The floating point value will be automatically coerced to an `int` by truncation towards zero.

Comment: An `id` variable gives the compiler a good idea of what it is: it's a reference to an Obj-C object. You are free to send messages to it. `void *` is the type that says, "This is an address, but I have no idea what of."

Comment: @Jeremy: regarding the first point: Yes, but the text is apparently trying to point out the differing type, so considering the level of understanding of the OP, I figured I would make that same point.

Comment: @Jeremy: regarding the second point: Thank you. I've updated my answer.